# flex regain lost focus

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I have a custom component with textbox & a poup button
as

```
<mx:HBox>   
    <mx:Text id="source" height="100%" width="40%" data="my text" />
    <mx:VBox backgroundAlpha="0" height="100%" borderThickness="0"> 
        <mx:PopUpButton enabled="true" id="editButton"  width="40" icon="@Embed('assets/images/Legends/editIcon.png')" 
            initialize="popUpButton_initialize()" 
            popUp="{actionMenuEdit}" 
            height="19" toolTip="Edit at segment"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:HBox>
```

I am using this custom component as the itemEditor for the datagrid

I have a problem with focus. I need to set focus to the text after popup buttton itemclick
The scenario is that I am typing text in the source text. If I go to popup button and click any item, the focus moves to the popup button, and I am unable to type in the text as the focus is lost.

I need to set the focus back to the source code after pop-up-button item-selection so that I can continue typing.
At the moment I need to click gain in the text and then I am able to type.

Answer (score 0):

```
source.setFocus()
```

Comment: Thanks Amarghosh but
I tried this but it is not working. If I give space then I am able to see the popup button highlighted & if I do Ctrl+Down Arrow  then popupbutton menu opens. It seems that teh focus is still on popupbutton.

Comment: where are you calling `source.setFocus()` from? Do it from the close event handler of the popup button

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a handler for the change event of the pop up button that sets the focus to your text box.

This will be something like this:

```
this.focusManager.setFocus(source);
```

or in your example:

```
<mx:HBox>   
    <mx:Text id="source" height="100%" width="40%" data="my text" />
    <mx:VBox backgroundAlpha="0" height="100%" borderThickness="0"> 
        <mx:PopUpButton enabled="true" id="editButton"  width="40" icon="@Embed('assets/images/Legends/editIcon.png')" 
                initialize="popUpButton_initialize()" 
                popUp="{actionMenuEdit}" 
                change="{this.focusManager.setFocus(source)}"
                height="19" toolTip="Edit at segment"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:HBox>
```

Comment: The change event may not be right for a popup button, but it would work for a combobox. You may need to change what event triggers the setFocus to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

may b this help u

```
if (flexApplication != "undefined") flexApplication.focus();
```